# Fixed Dimension Table Hiding/Unhiding

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

The technique I have used to hide/unhide a div is as follows:

```
$("#" + sectionId).css("display", "");      // unhide
$("#" + sectionId).css("display", "none");  // hide
```

This works fine, except I need to make this hiding/unhiding not affect the dimensions on the rest of the page.  That is, I do not want the act of *hiding* the content to shrink all the content around it.  In other words, I would prefer to have the dimensions of everything on the page remain as it would be if the div were always visible.  I've tried setting the div to zero height, but that doesn't seem to have an effect.

Note: these divs actually reside within a table, hence cells are resizing automatically to fit content (which I do not want).

Update: Ok, half the problem is resolved but note that this is a *table* not a *div* that I am trying to hide/unhide.  I need the table height to shrink down to zero but maintain its width.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `visibility='hidden'` and `visibility='visible'` instead:

```
$("#" + sectionId).css("visibility", "visible");  // unhide
$("#" + sectionId).css("visibility", "hidden");   // hide
```

This will keep the object physically in the page but it will be "invisible", as opposed to "removing" with `display`.

[**More info**](http://www.css3.com/visibility/).

---

### EDIT

As for the new/editted question:

> Ok, half the problem is resolved but note that this is a table not a div that I am trying to hide/unhide. I need the table height to shrink down to zero but maintain its width.

Set the table width to a fixed value and the hide the divs with content using `display` property:

```
<table style="width: 500px;">
  <tr><td>
    <div id='div1'>Some content</div>
  </td></tr>
</table>
```

When you now hide the `div1` using then code you've used in your question, the table width should stay the same width but shrink in height.

**EDIT2**: [A simple example](http://jsfiddle.net/juQWF/).

Comment: This worked except the <td> containing it is now fullsize.  I will try to shrink the height programatically, if possible.  By the way: I have had browser compatibility issues in the past with the "visibility" style but fortunately it seems to be working in this context.

Comment: actually its a <table> not <td>

Comment: @Ryan Delucchi, what do you mean with "<table> is now fullsize"?

Comment: @Czechnology I've just added an update to the original question and clarified:  This is actually a table I am hiding/unhiding.  I need to effectively shrink the height down to zero without changing the width (on hide).

Comment: @Ryan Delucchi, well but that's a whole other question now! See my editted answer.

Comment: Thanks!  I actually had to create multiple divs (one for each cell) which can be all hidden, in order to make this work.  Sheesh ... CSS is sure overly complicated ...

Comment: @Ryan Delucchi, well, if you always want to hide the whole table (not just single cells/rows), you could to it the other way around: `<div style="width: 500px;"><table id='table1'><!-- ... --></table></div>` and hide the table: `$("#table1").css("display", "none");`.

Comment: Ah yes, good call.  I didn't think that a div could be used for fixing the width utilized by a table like that.  I guess the "just wrap it in another div" solution is even *more* universally helpful than I originally thought.

Answer (score 7):

I believe you're looking for the CSS `visibility` property. http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_visibility.asp

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the [visibility](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_visibility.asp) instead:

```
//hide
$('#element').css('visibility', 'hidden');

//show
$('#element').css('visibility', 'visible');
```